# Persisting data to neo4j stand alone server

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently doing some R and D regarding moving some business functionality from an Oracle RDBMS to Neo4j to reduce join complexity in the application queries.  Due to the maintenance and visibility requirements for the data, I believe the stand alone server is the best option.

My thought is that within a java program I would pull the relevant data out of the Oracle tables, map it to a node object and persist it to neo4j (creating the appropriate relationships in the process).

I'm curious, with SDN over REST not being an optimal solution, what options are available for persistence.  Are server plugins or unmanaged extensions the preferred method or am I overcomplicating the issue as tends to happen from time to time.

Thank you!

Comment: Right now I'd go with either the JDBC driver, or a server extension written in SDN (if you want to use object-graph-mapping). it all depends on the use-case, you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

REST refers to a way to query the data over a network, not a way to store the data.  Typically, you're going to store the data on some machine; you then have the option of either making it accessible via RESTful services with the neo4j server, or just using java applications to access the data.

I assume by SDN you're referring to [spring data neo4j](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/).   Spring is a framework used for java applications, and SDN then refers to a plugin if you will for spring that allows java programmers to store models in neo4j.  One could indeed use spring-data-neo4j to read data in, and then store it in Neo4J - but again this is a method of how the data gets into neo4j, it's not storage by itself.

The storage model in most cases is pretty much always the same.  [This link](http://www.slideshare.net/aliraza995/neo4j-graph-storage-27104408) describes aspects of how storage actually happens.

Now -- to your larger business objective.  In order to do this with neo4j,  you're going to need to take a look at your oracle data and decide how it is best modeled as a graph.  There's a big difference between an oracle RDBMS and Neo4J in terms of how the data is represented.  Once you've settled on a graph design, you can then load your data into neo4j (many different options for doing that).

Will all of this "reduce join complexity in the application queries"?   Well, yes, in the sense that Neo4j doesn't do joins.  Will it improve the speed/performance of your application?  There's just no way to tell.  The answer to that depends on what your app is, what the queries are, how you model the data as a graph, and how you express the resulting queries over that graph.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that if I use spring data neo4j and the stand alone server the create node/relationship queries would use some form of spring neo4j rest to run the statements on the server.  Since this would have a performance impact, I want to try and avoid that.

I was looking at using the transactional http endpoint or possibly the jdbc driver, but I'm not familiar with what the pros and cons of each would be.

Comment: As far as the business objective and reducing complexity of joins for performance sake, that's part of the R&D objective.  The piece of the application I'm looking at pushing into neo4j is that of our product tree which is largely queried based on relationships, it seemed like a good fit since we often start at a category and drill through product properties to find the item or items which meet the required criteria.  It is the beginning and key piece of a polyglot persistence model that I'd like to convince the boss would meet the business requirements better than RDBMS.

Comment: I think you're combining/confusing several different topics here.  I'm not aware that anything like "spring neo4j rest" exists.  Spring neo4j is a set of mappings between spring models and neo4j objects.  REST is a method of accessing.  Yes, there would be a performance impact to doing queries over REST (it is generally slower) so don't do that.  If you're using spring data neo4j, you won't be using REST.   I think also you mean "embedded" neo4j rather than "stand alone".

Comment: As for using HTTP as an access method rather than JDBC, well JDBC will be faster, but you'll have to develop java code to use it.  HTTP will be slower, but more general; you'll be able to use non-java software to talk to it/query, and sometimes you'll be able to use regular clients (like browser) instead of custom code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am really confused.  Due to the functional requirements of what is being prototyped, an embedded neo4j is not a viable option as far as my research can determine.  I believe from further research that spring-data-neo4j can only access an embedded neo4j database and therefore I can use spring-data-neo4j-rest to access the remote neo4j server but it is not an optimal method due to chattiness over the wire.  For queries, I can use unmanaged extensions to reduce the network traffic, but what are my options to create/update nodes and relationships?

Comment: I am also confused by your mention of "unmanaged extensions".  What are you referring to?  By the way, SDN just writes to a neo4j database; it is in embedded mode when you're doing that I suppose, but your further discussion is drawing out points you weren't clear on initially.  If you use Neo4J's server REST endpoints, they can be used for arbitrary Cypher query, so you can do create, update, delete, and anything else over RESTful service.

Comment: I'm referring to unmanaged extensions as documented here: [link]http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.3/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

From the documentation on Spring Data Neo4j, it seems that the only way to connect to a remote server instance of neo4j is to use the spring-data-neo4j-rest package, which is well documented in these forums to not be the most optimal solution.  Perhaps I am misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: With all due respect, I think the scope of your question is well beyond what we can do on StackOverflow.  Your best choices will depend heavily on business aspects which you haven't disclosed.  I see the unmanaged extensions docs, but I know so little about your problem area it's impossible to tell whether the use of those is a good or bad idea.  (Your comment about using unmanaged exceptions to reduce network traffic makes no sense, but I acknowledge it probably makes sense in your business context with the particulars).

Comment: spring-data-neo4j-rest is *NOT* the only package you can use to access RESTful services.  You can do it with just about any web client.  (That's a big plus of REST).  But what you should use is again driven by the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, which you haven't stated.   Performance wise, there's nothing wrong with spring-data-neo4j-rest, most of the issues you may be seeing probably relate to REST, not that specific implementation.

Comment: I get that your business situation is probably sensitive and you don't want to post that on the net; you should consider a local consultant who you can provide those details to help with this.  Is a hammer a good tool?  If you don't tell me what you're trying to do, I can't say -- we want to be careful not to advise you that a hammer is a good tool for driving screws.

Comment: I think maybe the issue is that I provided too much information as to my question.  Based on the PS to the answer here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394930/trouble-reading-neo4j-rest-api-query-results-interatively/23396039?noredirect=1#23396039 -- I'm just wondering what the available options are for creating nodes on the server since the embedded database option doesn't work for the business problem.  I'm assuming , and maybe that's my mistake, that using the @NodeEntity annotation will send the create cypher statement using the REST API.